# Reference Cell in "GetPivotData" Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

My function is working correctly when I manually enter the  "CustomerAccoutNumber":

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of SalePrice]",
 [2017Sales.xlsx]GMBlitzOct!$A$6,"[2017Sales].[CustomerAccountNumber]","
 [2017Sales].[CustomerAccountNumber].&[Z4049200]")
```

But I would like to replace the "Z4049200" with a cell reference so I can copy and drag down for multiple rows, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, correct function should be:

> =GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of SalePrice]",[2017Sales.xlsx]GMBlitzOct!$A$6,"[2017Sales].[CustomerAccountNumber]"," [2017Sales].[CustomerAccountNumber].&["&A2&"]")